# Reference request for mixed Sobolev / Lebesgue space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Does anyone know this space? The author plays in an the article, it seems to me to be Banach and reflexive. Knowing his name already helps a lot, because he uses the norm of this space in the accounts.

- $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an open bounded  set.
- $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open bounded  interval.

$$\color{blue}{\boxed{V(\Omega \times I):=L^{\infty}(I;L^{2}(\Omega))\cap L^{p}(I;W^{1,p}(\Omega))}}$$

Comment: For $p=2$ I believe its called the energy space for incompressible Navier--Stokes, since if you formally test N-S against the solution $v$ itself you get
$ \frac{d}{dt} \| v\|_{L^2}^2 + \nu \|\nabla v\|^2_{L^2} = 0$. Integrating in time, you get $$ \|v(t)\|_{L^2}^2 + \nu \int_0^t  \|\nabla v(s)\|^2_{L^2} ds = \|v_0\|_{L^2}^2$$ so if the initial data $v_0$ is in $L^2$, then the solution is (formally) in $V(\Omega \times [0,t])$

Comment: (small typo, it should have been $\frac12\frac d{dt}$) Can you link to the article?